# how to edit category page in opencart 2?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

How can I make a page for categories that don't have a product in them to show
for example I have a category for shoes but for now I don't have a product to show
 but I want a page with description about this product can somebody help?

Comment: I don't know what your looking for exactly. No matter if a category has any product or not, you can create it and add your desired information to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add desired information to category pages in OpenCart -

1. Go to Admin panel > Catalog > Category > Edit category ( in which you want to show information ) > add **Description** > Save.
2. Done !! It will show above added information regardless of category  products.